# SharePoint List Form Footer JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I am trying to have a footer with a border (with color changing based on a value), and then add links after that (no background).

I was able to do them separately, but I cannot combine them successfully:

For the border:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "font-size": "10px",
        "border-top-width": "5px",
        "padding-top": "8px",
        "display": "flex",
        "justify-content": "center"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if([$Result] == 'Successfully Done', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen', if([$Result] == 'In Progress', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgSage', if([$Result] == 'Thinking about it', 'ms-bgColor-neutralLight', if([$Result] == 'Rejected', 'ms-bgColor-yellow', 'ms-bgColor-yellow')))) + ' ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary'"
    }
}
```

For the links:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-direction": "column",
        "justify-content": "flex-start",
        "align-items": "flex-start"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "References:",
            "style": {
                "font-weight": "bold"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "TestName1",
            "attributes": {
                "target": "_blank",
                "href": "TestLink1"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "TestName2",
            "attributes": {
                "target": "_blank",
                "href": "TestLink2"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "TestName3",
            "attributes": {
                "target": "_blank",
                "href": "TestLink3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add any mock image how you want to show the colored footer and links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON like below for SharePoint list form configure layout > footer settings:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "width": "100%"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "font-size": "10px",
                "border-top-width": "5px",
                "padding-top": "8px",
                "display": "flex",
                "justify-content": "center"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "class": "=if([$Result] == 'Successfully Done', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen', if([$Result] == 'In Progress', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgSage', if([$Result] == 'Thinking about it', 'ms-bgColor-neutralLight', if([$Result] == 'Rejected', 'ms-bgColor-yellow', 'ms-bgColor-yellow')))) + ' ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary'"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "column",
                "justify-content": "flex-start",
                "align-items": "flex-start",
                "margin-top": "20px"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "References:",
                    "style": {
                        "font-weight": "bold"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "txtContent": "TestName1",
                    "attributes": {
                        "target": "_blank",
                        "href": "TestLink1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "txtContent": "TestName2",
                    "attributes": {
                        "target": "_blank",
                        "href": "TestLink2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "txtContent": "TestName3",
                    "attributes": {
                        "target": "_blank",
                        "href": "TestLink3"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Make sure you are using correct **internal name** of your list columns in JSON. You can get the exact internal name of your columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ganesh, this one worked as I was imagining.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you. Keep using this platform for asking questions anything related to SharePoint!